# Excel formula and drag down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to calculate Stand BA (highlighted on the right). This average is obtained by taking the sum of each plot's BA/ac value and dividing by the number of plots (for this example, there are 11 #1024 plots). The number of plots is always different. What formula could I use to apply the StandBA column so that I can drag it all the way down by plot number?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,T:T)`.

It will return the average value from column `T`, and rows having the value of `A2` (then `A3`, `A4`...) in column `A` will be the only ones to be taken into consideration for the calculation of the average value.

**EDIT:**

Use `=IF(A2=A3,"",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,T:T))` if you want only the last rows of your `Plot Id` to contain the average formula (as shown on the screenshot in column `U`).

Example with columns `A:C`, formula pasted into `C2` and dragged down to the last row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Witherfield. I'm obtaining a Div/0 error when I use the formula in your edit. You are correct in saying that I want to only the last rows to contain the average formula for that specific plot #.

Comment: Update: I adjusted your formula so that it reads: =IF(A45=A51,"",AVERAGEIF(A45:A51,A1,T45:T51)) but I am getting a blank cell with the error ! point. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Also, will this formula allow me to drag down the entire column? Thanks.

Comment: @TheStallion, the first part of the `IF` formula is to check which row to display the average in (meaning, the first row in which `A` cell's content is not the same as the previous one's), therefore - when dragged down - it should be `A2=A3`, `A3=A4`, etc, consecutively.  In `AVERAGEIF()` then, `A:A` and `T:T` should refer to whole columns, as the formula choses the correct rows for the calculation using the second argument (`A2` in the second row, `A3` in the third, etc.).

Comment: I just realized the formula should start from `A2`, as your table has headers. My bad. I adjusted the answer. Copy the formula to `U2` and drag it down, it should produce `=IF(A2=A3,"",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,T:T))`, `=IF(A3=A4,"",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A3,T:T))`, etc. I've added a visual example to my answer as well.

Comment: I can understand your logic here, but for whatever reason, the formula is producing a value of 899.10 and copies that value for the last cell of each plot. It should be taking 30+45+15/3=30. Not quite sure why I'm getting the same value for each plot. enter image description here